# Preventing NPE on a google maps object

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am creating a project using google maps.But the google map object is not intialised in the beginnning.It happens at a later stage in the class.But when there is not internet connection , the further part of the class wont load.That is when i get a NPE at the listener of the map object.How do i prevent NPE on the google map object.My oncreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list_categories=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_categories);
         custom_layout = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout,null);
        iv_category_logo=(ImageView) custom_layout.findViewById(R.id.iv_category_logo);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(MainActivity.this);
        Config.isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (!Config.isInternetPresent) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            // Shuld be fail icon
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setMessage("Connection Not Available !" + "\n"
                    + "Please enable your Internet Connection");
            builder.setTitle("INTERNET CONNECTION");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        else{
            getcurrentlocation();


        }
        //I am getting the NPE at the googleMap object below.How do i initialise it?
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapFullScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Why dont you wrap the listener inside a simple null check? ie, `if(googlemap!=null){ /*your listener*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

1)Find your mapView by using findViewById().  Or your MapFragment if that's how you did it.

2)Call getMap() on your mapview or mapfragment.

Comment: This is the code is use further down in the class:  googleMap = ( (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                     R.id.map)).getMap();.Can i use it in the oncreate itself.

Comment: You can use it anytime after the fragment is created.  I don't know where that is in your code.  If it isn't created in onCreate, then you can't set the click listener yet.